# Low Connectivity on Wireless Xbox 360 Controller for Windows 7

Tags: pc, controllers

I bought a wireless Xbox 360 controller for my laptop. It seems to work fine when turning it on. However, it will only stay connected within 3 feet range of the receiver. I have a bluetooth USB receiver, a wireless keyboard, and a wireless mouse connected to the same laptop so maybe that's causing interference. But I have tried disconnecting them and still the range is low. Is my product defective or is there interference going on?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the receiver is defective.

I don't own one of these but have used one many times at my friends house. He had the same problem as you did and just exchanged it at the store and hasn't had any problems with it for over 1 year. If I'm correct, the range should be roughly 30 feet with direct distance from your laptop, so your best bet is to exchange it.

If its past the 30 day exchange time period Xbox has coverage on accessories for 6 months after purchase. Also if you lost your receipt but paid debit just include a screen shot of that purchase through your recent account transactions. If you can't figure out how to get free shipping just call 18004myxbox, let them know your situation ...complain a bit and they'll give you free shipping.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I am returning it back to Amazon and getting a free replacement.

Comment: glad I could be of assistance